# Is there always a homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ with ${\varphi|}_{H}=id_H$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $H\le G$.

Is there always a homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ with ${\varphi|}_{H}=id_H$?

Comment: Does $H \leq G$ just mean that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Nice question! No wonder you already got four upvotes. It would be helpful if you cold post alsomsome of your thoughts on this problem.

Comment: @HansEngler Hi, thanks! I'll keep this in mind for my future questions, as this one got an answer by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not.  For instance, consider $H = \{0,2\} \subseteq G = \Bbb Z/4 \Bbb Z$. There are exactly two homomorphisms $\varphi: G \to H$: one is the trivial homomorphism $\varphi(g) = 0$, and the other is the map
$$
\varphi(n) = 2n
$$
Neither of these satisfies your conditions.

Comment: A sufficient condition for this to be possible is that $G = H \oplus H'$ for some other subgroup $H'$.  Along these lines, the $\varphi$ necessarily holds if $H$ is projective, but this is impossible for finite $G$.

Comment: Thanks! I feel a bit silly now, as I thought this was clearly true and I tried to prove this (to prove something else, which is true (and I falsely thought it was true because of this)).